# Save the state of integers and textviews onpause()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

So I've seen a few questions on this topic but nothing really going into detail on how to do it and how to understand it.

The app I'm creating is for a class and it's an rpg type game

So I have the following textviews and integers(being put into textviews)

TextViews:

textViewStrName

textViewStrRace

textViewStrAlliance

textViewStrClass

---

Integers correlating to other textViews:

textViewGoldValue

textViewXPValue

textViewXPLimit

textViewLevel

textViewHP

textViewMP

---

So I know I have do to something with SharedPreferences but I have no idea how to utilize that.. or is there a way to save it to a database?

Sorry I'm still pretty new to android and I ask a lot of questions....

**EDIT**

```
protected void onPause() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPause();
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putInt("myvalue", gold);

    prefsEditor.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences myPrefs1 = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",  MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String textViewGoldValue = myPrefs.getInt("myvalue", -1);
}
```

Comment: ``SharedPreferences`` is the class to use.  Keep in mind that the values will be erased when the user uninstalls the App.  You can also just write/read a file that holds the values using Java's ``Reader`` and ``Writer`` classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sharedpreferences in this way

```
 SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putInt("myvalue", textViewGoldValue);

    prefsEditor.commit();
```

and you can get this using

```
 SharedPreferences myPrefs1 = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",  
MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    int prefName1 = myPrefs1.getInt("myvalue", -1);
```

and similar for the remaining ones.

and if you ned to have idea on database you can follow the link [here](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/sqlite-database.html)

Comment: so I did all that and when I get to the onResume() where I use the second portion of your example, String prefName1 = myPrefs.getInt (...) | it underlines myPrefs and says it cannot be resolved

Comment: Use this myPrefs1.getInt (...) instead of myPrefs.getInt (...)

Comment: after I do that it tells me to change : String textViewGoldValue = (...) to type int. when I do that, it says that textViewGoldValue is unused?

Comment: You need to use it its not a problem actually